# send object from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: validation, jsp, jstl

Well, it's been 10 years since the last time I did any programming. I'm trying to validate a text box and a date on a JSP form. I've set up a message object and can read from it fine after validating input data.

Basically, the user.jsp has a user object that it reads from the session object. This was set in a servlet UserController.java

the form action is set as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action='user.jsp' name="/MyApp/user.jsp">
```

If there is a data entry error on the user.jsp, the POST action takes the user back to the same page and shows the error.

Is there a way in EL to essentially do the following:

```
<%
request.setAttribute("user",user);
RequestDispatcher disp= getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/user.jsp");
disp.forward(request, response);
%>
```

Comment: The form should be posted to a controller, and the controller would validate the parameters, and dispatch to the appropriate JSP. That's the point of the MVC pattern. JSPs are views. They generate markup. Nothing more.

Comment: I thought one should perform basic formating validation in the jsp and content validation at the controller, no? If formating validation at the controller is ok, then so be it. Thx for your reply.